# negation before brackets

Tags: c++, random, operator-keyword

This is a follow-up question to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12157212/335858). I am trying to build a loop that produces a set of three random numbers until they match a particular pre-defined set of three arbitrary chosen numbers.

I'm still trying to figure out what operators to use for the program to accept the random numbers in any order but without any results.

I tried to your

```
!(first==one && second==two && third==three)
```

but it doesn't seem to work in c++. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I'm confused as to what exactly you're trying to do. If you asked a previous question, a link would be nice so people can get some background info.

Comment: I think you probably meant to comment on [one of the answers here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12157137/c-random-numbers-logical-operator-wierd-outcome).

Comment: I am not sure what the question is here?

Comment: Looking back at the link that @minitech provided, it looks like that code is the right answer. But without a more complete program (the smallest you can come up with that compiles, links, runs, and shows the problem) it's impossible to say what the problem is.

Comment: If this is related to another question, you should either post a link or, better yet, edit your previous question.

Answer (score 2):

The condition that you tried implies that `first`, `second`, and `third` are in the same specific order as `one`, `two`, and `three`. You could try all six permutations, but that would make for a rather unreadable program. A better solution would be to add values to vectors, sort them, and then compare for equality, like this:

```
vector<int> a;
a.push_back(first);
a.push_back(second);
a.push_back(third);
vector<int> b;
b.push_back(one);
b.push_back(two);
b.push_back(three);
sort(a.begin(), a.end());
sort(b.begin(), b.end());
if (a == b) ... // values match
```

Here is [a link to this snippet on ideone](http://ideone.com/tJQIj).

Comment: Thanks. I think that will do. From comments I gather that maybe I didn't make my idea clear enough. Once I make it run I'll explain it more substantially. Thx again.